# Can I login to my VPN via Ubuntu's nmcli tool, passing both username and password from the terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, nmcli

When I use `nmcli`, I am unable to pass a username to the command.

```
sudo nmcli con up id MyVPN --ask
```

Will only ask for my password. How can I get it to ask for both my username and password?